# How do I get my content to continue to the right instead of going down

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a bunch of photos at http://youngunsandco.com/photo-stories/diana but don't want them to be 3 on top of 3, I want them to be 6 in a row with a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom. There is no width set on any of the containers, body, etc. I have tried to set a width of 9999999999px; but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set a width on .entry  - this worked in Firefox.

```
.entry {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
width: 1900px;
 }
```